# Descending order of shortest paths in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, dijkstra

I have a weighted Graph using networkx and the topology is highly meshed. I would like to extract a number of paths between two nodes with distance minimization.

To clarify, the dijkstra_path function finds the weighted shortest path between two nodes, I would like to get that as well as the second and third best option of shortest weighted paths between two nodes.

I tried using all_simple_paths and then ordering the paths in distance minimization order but it is extremely time consuming when the network is meshed with 500 nodes or so.

Any thoughts on the matter? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a standard problem, I suggest you to google it. In short, you need to understand what it literally means that two paths are not equal, in terms of one edge.

Comment: Your bruteforce solution has 2 issues. First, as you've noticed, it's inefficient (it can take up to `n!` time). Second, it's incorrect: the second shortest path doesn't have to be simple. Consider a very light path with a very light cycle attached to it.

Comment: I'm curious - there have been a lot of questions posted recently about finding multiple shortest paths.  What's this from?

Answer (score 1):

Try networkx's `shortest_simple_paths`.